# Jssor slider embedded in WordPress - custom transition

Tags: jssor

I embedded Jssor slider (Image gallery with vertical thumbnail) in my WordPress (in the template of a Custom Post-type), according to the instructions at the page:

http://www.jssor.com/development/embed-jssor-slider-into-blogger-post.html

I would like:

1. to remove the autoplay
2. to have one only type of transition (fade) and to remove all others
   (rotate, zoom, etc.)

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

```
jssor_slider1_starter = function (containerId) {

    var _SlideshowTransitions = [
    //Fade
    { $Duration: 1200, $Opacity: 2 }
    ];

    var options = {
        $SlideshowOptions: {                                //[Optional] Options to specify and enable slideshow or not
            $Class: $JssorSlideshowRunner$,                 //[Required] Class to create instance of slideshow
            $Transitions: _SlideshowTransitions,            //[Required] An array of slideshow transitions to play slideshow
            $TransitionsOrder: 1,                           //[Optional] The way to choose transition to play slide, 1 Sequence, 0 Random
            $ShowLink: true                                    //[Optional] Whether to bring slide link on top of the slider when slideshow is running, default value is false
        }
    };
    var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$(containerId, options);
};
```

Reference: demos-no-jquery/simple-fade-slideshow.source.html